# How can I reload map chunks to their original state in SMP?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

One of the frustrating things about working with server mods is that if a mod updates with a new feature that requires you to find something that spawns, you won't be able to find it in any of the chunks that have been saved in the world. If you are on an SMP server that gets a lot of use, you really need to travel far to find these things (it could be a new type or ore or maybe a new type of tree that spawns maybe) Most chunks are still pristine and untouched but have been added to the world file because someone came by that chunk at one point.

It would be great if I could have chunks 'refresh' or 'rollback' to their original state instead of starting fresh on a new world.

Is there any way to do something like this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Deleting the [region file](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Region_file_format#Region_File_Location) should force the game to regenerate the chunks when they are entered.

> Region files are located in a subfolder of the world directory called "region", and have names in the form r.x.z.mcr, where x and z are the region's coordinates. The coordinates for the region a chunk belongs to can be found by taking the floor of the chunk coordinates divided by 32.

You can also use [World Edit's //regen](http://wiki.sk89q.com/wiki/WorldEdit/Region_operations#Regenerating) command to regenerate specific areas of the map.

Comment: Sounds like this would cause an entire region to be regenerated: 512x512 blocks, top to bottom of the world. That's a large chunk out of your world. Maybe not an issue for the OP, but definitely something that should be noted.

Comment: You're right, @MatthewScharley, it would, but I don't think there's any other way.

Comment: thats ok, I think this may solve my problem. When I finally look into this and know for sure this is what I want, I'll mark it as an answer and +1 it.

Comment: Alternatively, you can install World Edit on bukkit servers and use their //regen function, this regenerates the selected BLOCKS, so you can easily regenerate small areas without doing the entire chunk.

Comment: @TheMCZombi3 recommends only following this answer if you are using similar tools to MCEdit, or **really** know what your doing, as this process can reset your entire world, and delete any progress you have made.

Answer (score 2):

1. Get WorldEdit,
2. Select the area with `//pos1` and `//pos2`
3. `//expand vert` the selected area vertically (bedrock to sky)
4. Use the command `//regen` and that area will be reset back to normal as if no one touched it.